# Merge two dataframes with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes :

```
df_energy.info()
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> Int64Index: 34673 entries, 1 to 43228
> Data columns (total 6 columns):
> TIMESTAMP        34673 non-null datetime64[ns]
> P_ACT_KW         34673 non-null float64
> PERIODE_TARIF    34673 non-null object
> P_SOUSCR         34673 non-null float64
> SITE             34673 non-null object
> TARIF            34673 non-null object
> dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), object(3)
> memory usage: 1.9+ MB
> ```

and df1 :

```
df1.info()
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 38840 entries, 0 to 38839
> Data columns (total 7 columns):
> TIMESTAMP                 38840 non-null datetime64[ns]
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F1    38696 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F3    38697 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F5    38695 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F6    38695 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F7    38693 non-null float64
> ACT_TIME_AERATEUR_1_F8    38696 non-null float64
> dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(6)
> memory usage: 2.1 MB
> ```

I try to merge these two dataframes based on TIMESTAMP column :

```
merged_df_energy = pd.merge(df_energy.set_index('TIMESTAMP'), 
                     df1,
                     right_index=True,
                     left_index =True)
```

But I get this error :

> ```
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-190-34cd0916eb6a> in <module>()
>       2                      df1,
>       3                      right_index=True,
> ----> 4                      left_index =True)
>       5 merged_df_energy.info()
>
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
> ```
>
> in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index,
>   right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator)
>            37                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
>            38                          copy=copy, indicator=indicator)
>       ---> 39     return op.get_result()
>            40 if **debug**:
>            41     merge.**doc** = _merge_doc % '\nleft : DataFrame'
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
> ```
>
> in get_result(self)
>           215                 self.left, self.right)
>           216 
>       --> 217         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
>           218 
>           219         ldata, rdata = self.left._data, self.right._data
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
> ```
>
> in _get_join_info(self)
>           337         if self.left_index and self.right_index:
>           338             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \
>       --> 339                 left_ax.join(right_ax, how=self.how, return_indexers=True)
>           340         elif self.right_index and self.how == 'left':
>           341             join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = \
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py
> ```
>
> in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers)
>          1072         this, other = self._maybe_utc_convert(other)
>          1073         return Index.join(this, other, how=how, level=level,
>       -> 1074                           return_indexers=return_indexers)
>          1075 
>          1076     def _maybe_utc_convert(self, other):
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers)
>          2480             this = self.astype('O')
>          2481             other = other.astype('O')
>       -> 2482             return this.join(other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers)
>          2483 
>          2484         _validate_join_method(how)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers)
>          2493             else:
>          2494                 return self._join_non_unique(other, how=how,
>       -> 2495                                              return_indexers=return_indexers)
>          2496         elif self.is_monotonic and other.is_monotonic:
>          2497             try:
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py
> ```
>
> in _join_non_unique(self, other, how, return_indexers)
>          2571         left_idx, right_idx = _get_join_indexers([self.values],
>          2572                                                  [other._values], how=how,
>       -> 2573                                                  sort=True)
>          2574 
>          2575         left_idx = com._ensure_platform_int(left_idx)
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
> ```
>
> in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how)
>           544 
>           545     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
>       --> 546     llab, rlab, shape = map(list, zip(* map(fkeys, left_keys, right_keys)))
>           547 
>           548     # get flat i8 keys from label lists
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
> ```
>
> in _factorize_keys(lk, rk, sort)
>           718     if sort:
>           719         uniques = rizer.uniques.to_array()
>       --> 720         llab, rlab = _sort_labels(uniques, llab, rlab)
>           721 
>           722     # NA group
>
> ```
> C:\Users\Demonstrator\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\tools\merge.py
> ```
>
> in _sort_labels(uniques, left, right)
>           741         uniques = Index(uniques).values
>           742 
>       --> 743     sorter = uniques.argsort()
>           744 
>           745     reverse_indexer = np.empty(len(sorter), dtype=np.int64)
>
> ```
> pandas\tslib.pyx in pandas.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas\tslib.c:18619)()
>
> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'
> ```

Can you help me please to resolve this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas

result = pandas.merge(df_energy, df1, on='TIMESTAMP')
```

If you want to save it:

```
result.to_csv(path_or_buf='result.csv', sep=',')
```

Or check the columns:

```
result_fields = result.columns.tolist()
print (result_fields)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell me the output after you try this? 
This should work:

```
merged_inner = pd.merge(left=df_energy, right=df1, 
                       left_on='TIMESTAMP', right_on='TIMESTAMP')
```

Comment: Thank you it works . Kind regards :)

Comment: Just to clarify when you did `df_energy.set_index('TIMESTAMP'), 
                     df1,` you set Timestamp as an idex for df_energy but not df1, therefore a merge was not possible.